# How can computer parts suffer if the computer isn't protected by an UPS?

Tags: power-supply, ups

In datacenters it's common to use [Uninterruptible power supply (UPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) to protect the computers. They are used for several reasons, but one is that electronics possibly can suffer from the power grid if the power isn't "filtered".

Is it only the power supply unit of the computer that can suffer or can the computer parts also suffer? And how can they suffer? Does an [Uninterruptible power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) work differently to an [Power supply unit (PSU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29) or is the PSU already protecting the computer parts from the power grid?

Comment: You only mention a UPS.  The UPS protects the data from loss when the power cuts out quickly.  It's a PDU (Power Distribution Unit), which may be integrated into some UPSes, which regulates the output and provides the protection for the electronics.  A surge protector is another component which shouldn't be ignored.  Its function should be obvious, unless you're this guy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMriTkE3igY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, but I think there's a device here you haven't mentioned:  a **power conditioner**.  These devices take power from the wall and pass it through filters to make a (fairly clean) output power signal.  In some cases they also have automatic voltage regulation, and can boost/cut the power from the wall.  In certain cases, they are also tailored to the applications they are used in.  For example, APC makes a seperate lines of power conditioners and UPSes for home theater and computing, as they have different power usage profiles (home theaters tend to have high peak usage).

I don't have any hard numbers on this, but if the power signal is out of spec or the PSU you are providing with that power signal is poorly designed, damage may occur to the device.  Specifically what, I don't know, and others that know more will have to chime in.

Some UPSes perform a power conditioning function, but most don't.

Comment: A power conditioner is more properly called a Power Distribution Unit, or PDU.  ADC is a major distributor, and they sell many of these in rackmount profiles.

Comment: @reemrevnivek - What I was thinking of was more like http://www.apc.com/products/apcav/products/index.cfm?action=model&id=310

Answer (score 3):

An UPS is generally used to keep power to your system during a power outage. On the most basic level, it is just a battery bank connected with a relay and an inverter. When the power goes out the relay switches to the inverter(often just a modified square wave with off the shelf UPS).

Don't assume that the ups has any filtering without reading the spec's. Cheaper UPS's only give a direct feed from your outlet until there is an outage, so if you have dirty power from your outlet, it is likely you will have dirty power entering your electronics.

A PSU is different in the sense that it may not have a battery backup. A PSU on a computer generally just takes AC power and converts it to DC. There will be some filtering effects in this process but I would suggest still using a surge protector for any valuable electronics. The cost of a surge protector vs replacing is minuscule.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it only the power supply unit of the computer that can suffer or can the computer parts also suffer?

The power supply is the area that can be damaged by surges in the AC mains. But if the power supply is really damaged, and it delivers overvoltages in its output, the CPU and other parts can be damaged as well. It's all about failure propagation.

If you have a lightning strike, there's no telling what can happen. *For what it's worth*: if you protect your power supply with a surge protector or other power conditioning device, make sure that *all* connections to your computer (telephone line for modem / ethernet connection) are protected, so that in a lightning storm the surge currents can't find a back-door into damaging your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that the output of the PSU under load never changes instantly, due to the inductance of the transformer, the output inductors and the caps. The MOSFET *should* go pop before anything bad happens.

It's more like that the power supply will fail before delivering increased voltage, but if you want to be extra-safe, use a surge protector. I opened up a scope power supply (from a HP 54501A) to find it has spark gaps on the input mains. Don't see that quality much more.

Remember: most UPSes are not line interactive, and continue to supply voltage to your devices unless a complete power failure occurs. A cheapy UPS will not do anything. It might have some MOVs on the inputs, at best.

Answer (score 1):

UPS are used in data centers to prevent data loss and maintain services during power outages.

In alot of cases UPS's are just used to give the computer enough time to save the contents of RAM to the harddrive and properly shutdown. For an example if a computer was in the middle of a harddrive write during a power outage the file system might get corrupted.

In a data center application the UPS systems provide power long enough for backup generators to startup and usually allow for a few hours of operations if the generator fails to start. In telecom downtime is expensive so great lengths are taken to make sure power is never lost.

Interesting random fact: Data centers and telco central offices must have disconnects for all power sources in case there is a fire(to make it safe for firefighters to work). These are often big red buttons mounted on the wall for easy access. These often get hit by new guys and sales people wondering what they do and cause huge business losses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't answer my question. The question isn't about what happens with the software (e.g. data loss), but how the hardware parts are affected.